# Javascript changing DIV like slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

Required result: Simple JavaScript Script, that resets(changes) multiple div's, like image slideshow. Automatic and onButtonClick.

While the script is working automatic, everything works as it should be, but... If some button is pressed:

- Timing function "breaks", div panel is not shown for 10 seconds, bet different times. Sometimes 5 seconds, sometimes 3 seconds, even 1 second and refreshes all the time.
- And I haven't understood why, maybe because of timing too. Sometimes none of div's is shown or all of them are shown at the same time

A short example for code (I added comments, what I think that line should do):

```js
//about carousel
var panelAIndex = 0; //set default div
showAPanel(); // call function

$("#btn_about_1").on("click", function () {
 panelAIndex = 0; // set div
 showAPanel() // call function
});

$("#btn_about_2").on("click", function () {
 panelAIndex = 1; // set div
 showAPanel() // call function
});

function showAPanel() {
 var timer = "10000"; // 10 seconds timer
 var panelA = document.getElementsByClassName("about"); // get div's
 var btn_A_primary = document.getElementById("btn_about_1"); // get first button
 var btn_A_second = document.getElementById("btn_about_2"); // get second button

 for (var i = 0; i < panelA.length; i++) {
  panelA[i].style.display = "none"; // hide all div
 }
 panelAIndex++; // increse div id
 if (panelAIndex > panelA.length) {
  panelAIndex = 1
 } // if last panel, reset to first

 // change buttons
 if (panelAIndex == 2) {
  btn_A_primary.classList.remove("btn_primary");
  btn_A_primary.classList.add("btn_second");

  btn_A_second.classList.remove("btn_second");
  btn_A_second.classList.add("btn_primary");
 } else {
  btn_A_second.classList.remove("btn_primary");
  btn_A_second.classList.add("btn_second");

  btn_A_primary.classList.remove("btn_second");
  btn_A_primary.classList.add("btn_primary");
 }

 // show div
 $(panelA[panelAIndex - 1]).fadeIn('slow');

 // after 10 seconds call function again
 setTimeout(showAPanel, timer);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="about">
 <div id="about_image"></div>
 <div class="about"  id="about_1">
            //couple paragraphs 1
          </div>
 <div class="about" id="about_2">
             //couple paragraphs 2
          </div>
 <button class="btn_second" id="btn_about_2">BUTTON 2</button>
 <button class="btn_primary" id="btn_about_1">BUTTON 1</button>
</section>
```

Comment: You are setting a timeout to update the panel automatically, but you are not clearing the timeout in your onclick handler - you are adding a second timeout.

Comment: `var tId; tId = setTimeout(showAPanel, timer); .... clearTimeout(tId);`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: @SpoonMeiser Right.. Your answer fixed it. Thanks, can you submit it as answer?

Comment: Just delete it. It is a duplicate